# How to remove all zeros before the decimal point in a Double

Tags: swift, string

I have a double that I want to display as a string but without the zeros before the decimal point.

The following code removes the opposite of what I want, it removes all numbers after the decimal point.

```
    let myDouble = 0.77
    var myStringDouble = String(myDouble)

    if let dotRange = myStringDouble.range(of: ".") {
        myStringDouble.removeSubrange(dotRange.upperBound..<myStringDouble.endIndex)
    }

    print(myStringDouble)

   // ideal result based on double 0.77 would be .77
```

How can I remove all zeros before the decimal point in a Double/String?

Comment: `let result = myStringDouble.replacingOccurrences(of: "^0", with: "", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: Swift 4: `let s = String("\(myDouble)".drop(while: {$0 == "0"}))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `NumberFormatter`. Set `minimumIntegerDigits` to `0`.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 0

let myDouble = 0.77
let myStringDouble = formatter.string(for: myDouble)
```

If you want to remove any digits, not just a leading 0, to the left of the decimal, change `minimumIntegerDigits` to `maximumIntegerDigits`.

Note that this also shows the user a value in the proper locale format.

Comment: `@rmaddy` Your answer relates more to what I'm actually doing in my code since I'm already using `NumberFormatter()`, in fact is what I will be using but to be fair with `@vadian` I'm marking his response is the right answer since his solution answers what I originally asked. Thanks a lot, I did know I could specify that in my number formatting with `minimumIntegerDigits `.

Comment: Of course you are free to accept whichever answer you feel best answers your question. But what do you mean by *"his solution answers what I originally asked"*? Your question was never edited. Both answers answer what your question is asking. If you actually want to remove any digits, not just zero, to the left of the decimal place, then replace `minimumIntegerDigits` with `maximumIntegerDigits`.

Comment: Well, both solutions solve my problem but yours relates more to what I'm working on. I do want to remove all digits before the decimal point.  I say your answer relates more to what I'm doing because eventually, I will want to remove digits before the comma (,) as well I just never mention that in my question to simplify my question. I will change the answer to yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
let myDouble = 0.77
var myStringDouble = String(myDouble)

if let dotRange = myStringDouble.range(of: ".") {
    myStringDouble = myStringDouble.substring(from: dotRange.lowerBound) // lowerBound includes the decimal point
}

print(myStringDouble)
```

Comment: That would remove *all* digits before the decimal point, not only zeros, i.e. `10.77` becomes `.77`.

Comment: I know, Martin, but the OP seems to consciously remove everything before the decimal point

Comment: That's now how I understand *"... but without the **zeros** before the decimal point"*, but who knows.